# Eclipse: Can't import SWT

Tags: java, compiling, eclipse

The error says: "The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved."

[image: Screenshot]

I've been at this for the past 8 hours, tried just about everything:

1. Swap Workspace
2. Project->Properties->Java Build Path
3. Windows->Preference->Java Build Path

I've reinstalled Eclipse 3 times. (twice using Ubuntu Software center, Once, direct download from eclipse.org)

Comment: Can you post the file system path of `swt` and also your Java classpath?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben Where it finds SWT when importing I THINK is: `/home/dgood1/eclipse/plugins`. I used "Search" from the folders targetting filesysten. There are older versions of SWT, but it wasn't found by eclipse itself. 

... As far as classpath is concerned, shouldn't it be my workspace?... I used Default workspace so it's "home/dgood1/workspace"... In case you're looking for swt in my workspace, yes, it's in the same folder as my java program's folder, as seen in package explorer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems one of the posts I read was true. Some how the available SWT built in with the installed Eclipse is corrupted.

I downloaded the latest release, following http://www.eclipse.org/swt/eclipse.php.